# How does SGD works in Spark MLlib with Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, distributed-computing, apache-spark-mllib, bigdata

I am new to Spark and wonder what will happen in the background in terms of RDDs on the cluster if the trainOn method is invoked on a StreamingLinearAlgorithm e.g.

```
val regression = new StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD()
regression.trainOn(someStream)
```

StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD contains the actual model (LinearRegressionModel) as well as the learning algorithm (LinearRegressionWithSGD) as a protected member. In method trainOn, the following is happening:

```
data.foreachRDD { (rdd, time) =>
  if (!rdd.isEmpty) {
    model = Some(algorithm.run(rdd, model.get.weights))
}
```

From my understanding, the streaming data is chunked every x seconds and the chunked data is put in an RDD. So every x seconds the learning algorithm is applied to a new RDD. The actual learning magic happens somewhere in GradientDescent, where the RDD data and the previous model weight vector is the input and the updated weight vector is the output.

```
 val bcWeights = data.context.broadcast(weights)
 // Sample a subset (fraction miniBatchFraction) of the total data
 // compute and sum up the subgradients on this subset (this is one map-reduce)
 val (gradientSum, lossSum, miniBatchSize) = data.sample(false, miniBatchFraction, 42 + i)
    .treeAggregate((BDV.zeros[Double](n), 0.0, 0L))(
      seqOp = (c, v) => {
        // c: (grad, loss, count), v: (label, features)
        val l = gradient.compute(v._2, v._1, bcWeights.value, Vectors.fromBreeze(c._1))
        (c._1, c._2 + l, c._3 + 1)
      },
      combOp = (c1, c2) => {
        // c: (grad, loss, count)
        (c1._1 += c2._1, c1._2 + c2._2, c1._3 + c2._3)
      })
 ...
 val update = updater.compute(
      weights, Vectors.fromBreeze(gradientSum / miniBatchSize.toDouble),
      stepSize, i, regParam)
 weights = update._1
 regVal = update._2
```

How is the weight vector updated? Does it work in parallel? I thought an RDD is split up into partitions and the distributed. I can see that the input weights are broadcasted in the spark context and treeAggregate is used, to sum up, the gradients but I can still not grasp which actual map-reduce task is taking place and which part is happening in the driver and which in a parallel way. Can anyone explain what is happening in detail?